# JavaScript Login/Register Not Validating session Storage

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use data retrieved from session storage to validate a newly registered user.  It just needs to be in session storage for this project. Basically, the new user registers on a Signup Page; the email and password are saved in session storage; then they should be able to log in through the regular login page as long as the tab is opened. Even though the user input is set in the session storage, I am unable to validate the user in the regular login screen afterwards.  I keep receiving the error "username/password do not match".  What am I missing that is causing it not to validate? Any help is much appreciated.

JavaScript

```
// TISSUE Login Script

//Function called when form is submitted
//Validates form and allows login

function validate() {
    'use strict';

    var UserName = document.getElementById('UserName').value;
    var email = "adrian@tissue.com";
    var email1 = "admin@tissue.com";
    var Password = document.getElementById('Password').value;
    var pass = "welcome1";
    var pass1 = "admin123";

// stored data from the register-form

    var storedName = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
    var storedPw = sessionStorage.getItem('password');

// entered data from the login-form

    var userName = document.getElementById('UserName');
    var userPw = document.getElementById('Password');


    if ((UserName == email) && (Password == pass)) {
        window.location.href = "Issues.html";
        return false;
    } else if ((UserName == email1) && (Password == pass1)) {
        window.location.href = "subscription_dashboard.html";
        return false;
    } else if ((userName == storedName) && (password == storedPw)) {
        window.location.href = "Issues.html";
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("username and/or password do not match");
        return false;
    }
}

// End of Validation

function init() {
    'use strict';

    if (document && document.getElementById) {
        var loginform = document.getElementById('loginform');  
        loginform.onsubmit = validate;
    }
}

window.onload = init;
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Tissue: Titan Issue Tracking</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="description" content="Issue Tracking System"/>
      <meta name="author" content="Stephen Morris">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tissue.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <h2>TISSUE: Titan Issue Tracker</h2>
         <div class="topnav">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="Registration.html">SignUp</a>
         </div>
         <div id="loginwrap">
            <h1>Login</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="signupForm">
            <form action="Issues.html" method="post" id="loginform" onsubmit="return validate()">
               <div class="labels">
                  <label for="UserName">UserName:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="rightTab">
                  <input type="email" name="UserName" id="UserName" class="input-field" placeholder="E-mail Address" required>
               </div>
               <div class="labels">
                  <label for="Password">Password:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="rightTab">
                  <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required>
               </div>
               <div id="loginwrap">
                  <hr>
                  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
       </div>
         <div class="copyright">
         Copyright &copy; 2018 Titan Issue Tracker
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

New User JavaScript

```
// UserStore Module

// Store Username and Password in sessionStorage

function newUser () {

    var userName = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    sessionStorage.setItem("userName", userName);
    sessionStorage.setItem("password", password);

}
```

New User Registration HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Tissue: Titan Issue Tracking</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="description" content="Issue Tracking System"/>
      <meta name="author" content="Stephen Morris">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tissue.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <h2>TISSUE: Titan Issue Tracker</h2>
         <div class="topnav">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="Login.html">Login</a>
         </div>
         <div id="loginwrap">
            <h1>Create New Account</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="signupForm">
            <form action="Issues.html" method="post" id="loginform" onsubmit="return newUser()">
               <div class="labels">
                  <label for="email">* E-mail:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="rightTab">
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter Your E-mail" required>
               </div>
               <div class="labels">
                  <label for="Password">* Password:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="rightTab">
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Create Password" required>
               </div>
               <div class="labels">
                  <label for="password">* Confirm Password:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="rightTab">
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password1" class="input-field" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
               </div>
               <div id="loginwrap">
                  <hr>
                  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
       </div>
         <div class="copyright">
         Copyright &copy; 2018 Titan Issue Tracker
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is you're setting storage with a name and trying to get item with another key name e.g:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("userName", userName);
var storedName = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
```

it should be instead:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("userName", userName);
var storedName = sessionStorage.getItem("userName");
```

or

```
sessionStorage.setItem("email", userName);
var storedName = sessionStorage.getItem("email");
```

Hope it helps.